# How to Refresh Fragments with swipe to refresh widget?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

I wanted to refresh my fragment with SwipeToRefresh widget.

This is my **XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_drawable"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Fragment_1">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
   
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is my **JAVA code**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        newconfig= getResources().getConfiguration();
        db=new DBHandler(getActivity());
        swipeRefreshLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        if(book.size()==0) {
            book = db.readCourses();
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        BookFragAdapter adapter = new BookFragAdapter(Fragment_land1.this,book);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               this.onRefresh();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(Fragment_land1.this).attach(Fragment_land1.this).commit();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

When I try to refresh it doesn't refresh and the widget doesn't stops after 250ms. I assume that the code inside **onRefreshListener** is not actually executing therefore the next line is ignored. I don't know how change it with. I surfed in **Stackoverflow** and **Developer.android** none of the answers solved my problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should refresh your data only . You don't remove and add same fragment again.  Move all data loading call inside a method and call that method on refresh .

Comment: @ADM This method was one of the accepted answer for similar question like this... that's why I tried it and I need to refresh entire fragment not just the data.That's my task

Answer (score 0):

first check that you have added dependencies in build.gradle file
i.e implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

Secondly swipe to refresh layout tag should start from start instead of fragment
for eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/swipe"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/gradient_drawable"
 android:padding="10dp"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context=".Fragment_1">

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>    
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

third then write swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener code in java file

Comment: dependency is included... it doesn't matter when to start the swipe layout unless the widget that has to be refreshed is outside the layout...